# How to name an eval script file in a browser debugger tools?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, getscript

In a javascript file, I have a jquery function that loads a javascript file using `getScript`. The problem is when I want to debug the downloaded script, it is not easy to find it in debugger tools. It looks like this:

[image]

Where it says eval code, thats the downloaded script. Is there a way I can put a name on that? Like for example in the script thats being downloaded, I want something like

`namespace("control.js");`

Then in the debugger tools, instead of 'eval code' it will say 'control.js'.

Does anyone know a way for this?

Thanks

Comment: ideally crossbrowser, but to start off, IE11.

Comment: Not certain about ie, though should be possible at chromium / chrome

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a late response, but this might be useful for other people still;

`//# sourceURL=url`

The above can be added to the end of an eval string, to indicate its source. I am not sure if it would show up properly in those debugger tools. But it does at least show up properly when it is logging data in chrome.

source: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/#toc-sourceurl

Answer (score 0):

At chromium / chrome , should be able to open `console` -> select `Sources` tab, select resource from left panel -> copy source of resource -> at left panel select `Snippets` -> right click in `Snippets` panel , select `New` -> name snippet when `*Script snippet #n` highlighted in left panel -> paste source of selected resource into middle panel -> select all pasted source of resouce -> right click while source highlighted -> select `Add to Watch` -> at right panel selected snippet should be listed at `Watch Expressions`

Comment: What does snipplets have to do with jQuery's getScript?

Comment: @epascarello _"What does snipplets have to do with jQuery's getScript?"_ ? `Snippets` at chromium / chrome dev tools . Read OP at _"The problem is when I want to debug the downloaded script, it is not easy to find it in debugger tools."_ , _"Where it says eval code, thats the downloaded script. Is there a way I can put a name on that?"_?

Comment: I mean add a name on it using js code so it always shows the name automatically.

Comment: @omega Change name of external resource loaded at document "automatically" - in developer console ? Not certain if this is possible using `js` loaded at page

Comment: Yeah, so if I load external 'A.js' I want it to show 'A.js' instead of eval code automatically.

Comment: @omega See https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/authoring-development-workflow . Not certain if requirement of "automatically" renaming externally loaded resource is possible without creating custom build of chromium.

Comment: Entire page, including links at bottom of page , e.g., _"My workflow: Never having to leave the DevTools | remy sharp"_ , see also https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging , https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/workspaces